# Android Global Var

Tags: java, android, global-variables

I know this has been asked before(and I have read lots of posts here about them) but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I want to set some things up as global variables to use throughout my app. So I created a new folder (which I think created a new app?) with a class in it :

[image]

Which is all good. In the Global.java I have the following:

```
package com.directenquiries.assessment.tool.Globals;

import android.app.Application;
import android.os.Environment;

public class Global extends Application {
      public String foo;
      public String SDcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();


    }
```

My Manifest file now looks like: (which I think might be the culprit?)

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.directenquiries.assessment.tool"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginPageActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login_page" >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

    <application
       android:name="Global" 
       android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </application>


</manifest>
```

And I'm trying to call the variable back in my LoginPageActivity like:

```
String SDLoc = ((Global) this.getApplication()).foo;

        TextView obs = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        obs.setText(SDLoc);
```

But my app falls over with:

```
09-11 14:14:19.354: W/dalvikvm(5339): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40c4f1f8)
09-11 14:14:19.359: E/AndroidRuntime(5339): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-11 14:14:19.359: E/AndroidRuntime(5339): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to com.directenquiries.assessment.tool.Globals.Global
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: You use Upper Cast. Application havent Global's methods

Comment: Sorry, Do you mind elaborating? I don't understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify  `public String foo` to  `public final static String foo` and than you can refere to as  `Global.foo`.
You don't need to put Global class in another package.

Comment: Thank you so much for this, and for the detailed reasoning behind it. Really appreciate it. Will mark as answer when I can

Comment: +1 It's not the cleanest way to go, but it works. Should make sure to make the fields final if they're constants.

Comment: yap , thanks for the final add, I'll modify the post. you are right

Answer (score 2):

User below manifest.xml

1. don't declare two application tags
2. your application class is in sub package so that you need to add relative package path like following

**android:name=".Globals.Global"**

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:name=".Globals.Global">
    <activity
        android:name=".LoginPageActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_login_page" >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```